# Do all STL containers return their elements by reference?

Tags: c++, stl

I am learning STL these days and I was wondering if STL containers *return by reference*?

e.g:

```
vector.first();
map[key];
*vector.begin();
Or any possible return that ends with element (or value type) of container
```

e.g:

```
std::vector<int> elements;
elements.push_back(20);
elements[0]=60; // this will also change the value
elements.front() = 23; // even the functions also behave same way like subscript operator
```

is this the case with all containers? or there are some points to consider which I didn't show?

Comment: "for e.g."? What do you think "e.g." means? Why not just use English if the foreign words are confusing, as in "for example" and "another example"?

Comment: I'm finding the question very unclear. "If all STL containers return by reference" -- what is that supposed to mean? First off, you should probably say "standard library containers". Second, who's returning what? Do you have a specific set of member functions in mind? Or are you asking about member functions that *don't* return by reference? (Like `pop_back()`?)

Comment: @Kerrek: I fixed the e.g. as the "for e.g." was redundant. For future visitors: http://ancienthistory.about.com/od/abbreviations/f/ievseg.htm

Comment: @Kerrek : rather than giving such a lecture  , you could've said "you shouldn't do such things" and i'd have listened to you. I don't know why question is not clear to you when others easily understood it ( i am not C++ std guy who's gonna write everything very precisely)

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: But containers don't return anything, member functions and functions do (and I don't think that's already _very_ precisely, just _correct_).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Returning the added element, or the container in container member functions is not possible in a safe way. STL containers mostly provide the *"strong guarantee"*. Returning the manipulated element or the container would make it impossible to provide the strong guarantee (it would only provide the "basic guarantee"). An explanation of these terms is provided at boost's website on *[Exception-Safety in Generic Components](http://www.boost.org/community/exception_safety.html)*. See below from [Boost's website](http://www.boost.org/).

- The *basic guarantee*: that the invariants of the component are preserved, and no resources are leaked.
- The *strong guarantee*: that the operation has either completed successfully or thrown an exception, leaving the program state exactly as it was before the operation started.
- The *no-throw guarantee*: that the operation will not throw an exception.

Back to the topic: Per this [previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175972/stl-container-function-return-values/3223863#3223863), the reason behind this is, that returning something could possibly invoke an copy-constructor, which may throw an exception. But the function already exited, so it fulfilled its main task successfully, but still threw an exception, which is a violation of the strong guarantee. You maybe think: **"Well then lets return by reference!"**, while this sounds like a good solution, its not perfectly safe either. Consider following example:

```
MyClass bar = myvector.push_back(functionReturningMyClass()); // imagine push_back returns MyClass&
```

Still, if the copy-assignment operator throws, we don't know if push_back succeeded or not, thus indirectly violating the strong-guarantee. Even though this is not a direct violation. Of course using `MyClass& bar = //...` instead would fix this issue, but it would be quite inconvenient, that a container might get into an indeterminate state, just because someone forgot a &.

A quite similar reasoning is behind the fact that `std::stack::pop()` does not return the popped value. Instead `top(`) returns the topmost value in a safe way. after calling top, even when a copy-constructor, or a copy-assignment constructor throws, you still know that the stack is unchanged.

Comment: I don't know anything about strong guarantee :( I'd love if you could explain a bit more about this property in simple words , thanks

Answer (score 2):

All the *types* of containers (sequence, associative) are designed to provide a consistent interface (where possible). It makes learning them relatively easy and using them even easier (as long as you've learnt them properly! ;) )

So for example, `operator[]` for all containers will return a reference to the entity indexed (in the case of the associate containers, it will be created first). For the sequence containers this raises an interesting point about bounds checking - but that's a different story. Similarly, if you take any other common operation (`insert` etc.) will have a similar interface. Your favourite reference will typically provide all the information you need.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the overloaded `[]` operator for stl containers return a reference. So in your examples above the values in `m` and `elements` will be altered.

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/operator%5B%5D/ :

The definition or operator[] for vector is:

```
reference operator[] ( size_type n );
const_reference operator[] ( size_type n ) const;
```

Where 'Member types `reference` and `const_reference` are the reference types to the elements of the vector container (generally defined as `T&` and `const T&` respectively in most storage allocation models).'

Edit: Be aware that not all stl containers have an overloaded `[]` operator. Those that don't are: `list`, `multimap`, `multiset`, `priority_queue`, `queue`, `set` and `stack`.

Comment: It may also be important to note that `std::map`'s `operator[]` does not have a `const` overload because it must insert into the map if the key doesn't already exist. Use `map::find` if `const`ness is required.

Comment: Not quite true with valarrays.  The non-const version returns a reference, while the const version returns a copy.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<bool>` is allowed to return something else than a reference to bool (assuming you really mean the standard library, not the SGI STL). But it is also generally seen as a mistake that does not deserve to be called a container.